# How To Speed Up Update SQL

Tags: sql, firebird

I have 480 Update SQL statements which I am executing using ADScript component in Delphi 2010.

Update SQL updates data in only one table called MY_BOOK, but there is a join with MY_BOOK_HEADER table. Below is the Update SQL, which is taking 81 seconds to execute all 480 Update SQL statements. Any idea how could I improve the speed of these 480 Update SQL statements ?

Update SQL:

```
Update MY_BOOK MB SET BOOK_NAME = 'Book Name1' , BOOK_DESCRIPTION = 'Book Desfcription1' 
Where MB.BOOK_TYPE = 4 And 
Exists (Select 1 from MY_BOOK_HEADER MBH 
            Where  
                MBH.HEADER_BOOK_CODE = '127518010109038'
                And MBH.FK_BOOK_GROUP =  '{79B79C33-CE56-4084-912B-6DD9F70B3DC4}'
                And MBH.PK_BOOK_HEADER = MB.SK_BOOK_HEADER
        );
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need 480 of those? What changes between these statements?

Comment: Probably a lack of indexes.  If you EXPLAIN your query plan, I'll bet TABLE SCAN is involved.

Comment: I am importing data from an excel file, so there is a loop, in that loop lots of SQL were executing and it was slowing down the application, so I am just holding all the SQLs in a ADScript component and once data collection is over, then I am executing them as -> ADScript.ValidateAll;  then ADScript.ExecuteAll;

Comment: What is the DDL of the tables involved, what indexes do you have on those tables? Also replacing the exists with `MB.SK_BOOK_HEADER = (SELECT MBH.PK_BOOK_HEADER ....)` might help.

Comment: @duffymo: Query plan is taken from Flamerobin--> Executing...
Done.
125058 fetches, 4 marks, 0 reads, 0 writes.
0 inserts, 2 updates, 0 deletes, 41675 index, 0 seq.
Delta memory: 128472 bytes.
MRP_BOM: 2 updates. 
2 rows affected directly.
Total execution time: 0.256s
Script execution finished.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel: replacing exists is not that much helpful, because I need to use IN instead of =, because it returns multiple records.

Comment: @VishalTiwari Depending on the number of rows, IN may very well be preferable here. But as it stands, you are simply not providing sufficient information.

Comment: 125,058 fetches doesn't look promising.  Looks like it's O(N)

Comment: You should add DDL of both tables involved and few example statements, at least. Otherwise, our answers won't fit your real needs, most likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **merge** statement, like this....:

```
merge into MY_BOOK MB
using MY_BOOK_HEADER MBH
  on (MB.SK_BOOK_HEADER = MBH.PK_BOOK_HEADER and
      MB.BOOK_TYPE = 4 and
      MBH.HEADER_BOOK_CODE = '127518010109038' and
      MBH.FK_BOOK_GROUP =  '{79B79C33-CE56-4084-912B-6DD9F70B3DC4}')
when matched then
  update set
    MB.BOOK_NAME = 'Book Name1',
    MB.BOOK_DESCRIPTION = 'Book Desfcription1';
```

Reference: [`MERGE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-dml-merge.html)

Comment: Thanks for correcting my answer at MB.BOOK_TYPE = 4.

Answer (score 0):

Below answer I got it from Firebird group. This answer is just for knowledge sharing.

Comments from Firebird Group is as below which includes Execute Block statement as well:

If PK is your integer primary key for MY_BOOK, then you should be able 
to do something like this:

```
execute block returns(Changes integer) as
declare variable mbPK integer;
begin
Changes = 0;
for select distinct MB.PK
from MY_BOOK MB
join MY_BOOK_HEADER MBH on MBH.PK_BOOK_HEADER = MB.SK_BOOK_HEADER
where MB.BOOK_TYPE = 4
and Upper(Trim(MBH.HEADER_BOOK_CODE)) = Upper(Trim('127518010109038'))
--UPPER and TRIM doesn't make any difference to a constant containing 
--only digits and no whitespace...
And MBH.FK_BOOK_GROUP = '{79B79C33-CE56-4084-912B-6DD9F70B3DC4}'
into :mbPK do
begin
update My_Book SET BOOK_NAME = 'Book Name1', BOOK_DESCRIPTION = 
'Book Description1'
where PK = :mbPK;
Changes = Changes + ROW_COUNT;
end
suspend;
end
```

'Changes' and 'suspend' is not required, but whenever I use EXECUTE 
BLOCK myself, I prefer to add such a variable to ascertain that I only 
update the ten records I want to update and not one million due to 
forgetting something important in the JOIN or WHERE clauses.

I think execute block can particularly improve performance if

a) You only want to reduce a small fraction of the records in My_Book, 
and/or
b) the EXISTS clause is complicated and time consuming

If both My_Book and My_Book_Header are small tables with sensible 
indexing, using execute block may be of little or no help.